# sqlalchemy one to many relations where this same foreign key is used twice in model

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a simple model like this

```
class ChatMessage(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'chat_messages'
   id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('messages.id'))
   sender_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))
   receiver_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))
```

And I try to add messages relation to user.

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    chat_messages = relationship("ChatMessage", backref="participants",
                             foreign_keys="[ChatMessage.sender_id, ChatMessage.receiver_id]")
```

it gives:

InvalidRequestError: One or more mappers failed to initialize - can't proceed with initialization of other mappers.  Original exception was: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship User.chat_messages - there are multiple foreign key paths linking the tables.  Specify the 'foreign_keys' argument, providing a list of those columns which should be counted as containing a foreign key reference to the parent table.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looks like defining a primaryjoin helps a little bit, just append doesn't work now

```
class User(Backend.instance().get_base()):

   __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    chat_messages = relationship("ChatMessage", backref="participants",
                             primaryjoin="User.id==ChatMessage.sender_id or User.id==ChatMessage.receiver_id")
```

Answer (score 6):

Set up the special relationship after both classes have been created.

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, relationship, backref

engine = sa.create_engine('sqlite:///test.db', echo=True)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
Base = declarative_base(bind=engine)


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)


class ChatMessage(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'chat_messages'
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    sender_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey(User.id))
    receiver_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey(User.id))
    content = sa.Column(sa.String, nullable=False)

    __table_args__ = (
        sa.CheckConstraint(receiver_id != sender_id),
    )

    sender = relationship(User, foreign_keys=sender_id, backref='sent_chat_messages')
    receiver = relationship(User, foreign_keys=receiver_id, backref='received_chat_messages')


User.chat_messages = relationship(ChatMessage, primaryjoin=sa.or_(
    User.id == ChatMessage.sender_id,
    User.id == ChatMessage.receiver_id
), backref=backref('participants', uselist=True, viewonly=True), viewonly=True)
```

`viewonly=True` is used because this relationship uses a custom join and SQLAlchemy wouldn't know what to do if the data changed. For example, if you append to participants, would it add the user as the sender, or the receiver?